# I can send email but when i try to reply i get a error message

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010

We currently have Exchange server 2010, and lately have been receiving a lot of complaints that when users try to REPLY to an email received they get delivery failure message
this only happens when they reply

thank you

Comment: As its currently written, this is just too broad. So many things can cause this. What have you tried so far? what configuration are the clients on? (OS, version of outlook, etc)

Comment: Definitely need more information for this.  Can you post the NDR?

Comment: Clients are running windows 7 pro, with outlook 2007. its setup through Microsoft exchange,

Comment: have not tried anything yet, and I will post the ndr in a bit

Answer (score 0):

I would put my money on a typo or miss in the config of the account. The "sent from" of "reply to" address has a typo and thus when someone is trying to reply the email address that the email client the receiver uses tries to send it to an address that does not exists and therefor it bounces.

When configuring the email client there is most likely a field where you type in the email address that you are configuring that again is often used as the "sent from" / "reply to" and if you get it wrong the above behavior happens.